# Github push only one branch issue

Tags: git, github

I have master and dev branches.

I need to reset dev branch and I did.

```
git push --force --set-upstream origin dev
```

It is updated, but on github page appeared button with "pull request" offering to merge changes with master branch. But I dont want to merge it to master yet. Should I ignore this "pull request" button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pull request button is just a convenience of GitHub, it sees that you have modified code in dev branch and offers a simple way to create a pull request from that. If you do not want to create a pull request (yet), simply don't press that button.